# New target column based on a pattern

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe:

```
source    target              
jan       feb                               
mar       apr                 
jun                       
feb       aug                                            
apr       jul                                            
oct       dec                     
aug       nov       
dec       may
```

The output dataframe would be:

```
source    target    new_target              
jan       feb       nov                        
mar       apr       jul                  
jun                              
feb       aug       nov                                     
apr       jul       jul                                           
oct       dec       may              
aug       nov       nov
dec       may       may
```

The aim is to create `new_target`column based on a logic like - for example, `jan` in source has value `feb` in `target`. This in turn, `feb` in source has a value `aug` in `target`, and so on `aug` has `nov` in `target` column.

So the `new_target` column values for `jan, feb and aug` will be `nov`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a dict for mapping the target, then apply it to every target

```
m = dict((zip(df.source, df.target)))
def mapper(x):
    for i in range(len(m)):
        x = m.get(x, x)
    return x   

df["new_target"] = df.target.apply(mapper)
```

Comment: Thanks @Allen, this would give `aug` as output in `new_target` column for first row

Comment: Fixed and please check again. Introduced a bug while trying to simplify the code.

Comment: Works perfect @Allen. Hope it wouldn't have an impact on run-time while running on large datasets, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(item):
    lookup = dict(zip(df["source"].values, df["target"].values))
    item = item
    while item in lookup.keys():
        item = lookup[item]
    return item
df["new_target"] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row["source"]), axis = 1)
```

Comment: It works correctly unless you have source == target - then it is infinite loop

Comment: @Lemon no rules for `source == target` so far, so I suppose there is no such condition

Comment: I know, thats the only issue i found after running your code, other than that well done :)

Comment: Thanks @ComplicatedPhenomenon, works good! And hope it wouldn't have an impact on run-time while running on large datasets